# Which regex should I use to ignore auto-generated TODOs in IDEA?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, regex-negation

In my TODO list in IntelliJ, I'd like to ignore auto-generated TODOs such as:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

I'm trying the following regex without success:

```
\btodo\b^(?!Auto-generated).*
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore them? Remove the TODO if you have implemented the method. Let it there as a reminder if you haven't, because it means that you still have to do something.

Comment: Of course, but in my case lots of TODOs were not added by me, moreover I'm dealing with a code base not completely under my responsibility. I am trying to filter items which are just cluttering my TODO list.

Comment: Ah, OK. It's indeed usual for newbies to let those TODOs there forever and don't care about them. I just wanted to point out that this was not good practice, and that those TODOs were supposed to be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` is not placed correctly. Try this:

```
TODO (?!Auto-generated).*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TODO\s?(?!Auto-generated)
```

does this work?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to account for the space (and anything that might precede it) and why did you put [] around it? it's nowhere in the phrase that you want to match

```
TODO(?!.*Auto-generated).*
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. For the record, [ and ] were added by mistake (I've edited the question just in case).

Answer (score 0):

```
// \btodo\b^(?!\[Auto-generated\]).*
// 
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
// Match the characters “todo” literally «todo»
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
// Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
// Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!\[Auto-generated\])»
//    Match the character “[” literally «\[»
//    Match the characters “Auto-generated” literally «Auto-generated»
//    Match the character “]” literally «\]»
// Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
```

So basically this regex will probably never match. You match a word and then you match the start of the string? How can this ever happen? Also you ignore //, your capitalization is wrong and you escape brackets inside your negative lookahead. This does not seem to match your input...

Comment: Just for the record, it would't work anyway but the extra [ and ] were added by mistake (my bad). I've just edited the question.

Comment: @TiagoFernandez I know that it wouldn't work. I just wanted to explain to you why instead of just giving you the solutions, thus forcing you to think and solve this problem. So at the end you learn something :)